# Invalid json response body at powerva.microsoft.com - unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, power-virtual-agents

I'm trying to publish an update from my bot framework composer upwards to my PVA instance.

I continue to get this error yet it somewhat goes up? But also has a second always loading profile while I do this?

Should have just been published and given me a green check. Below is the error I get, but I'm not provided any logs or details

"invalid json response body....Unexpected end of JSON Input"

[Bot Framework Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f55iP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is the thread I created - but I was also able to solve by reinstalling 3 times https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9087